# Filter System Files from File Path with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Daniel provided the VBA below to extract a date from a file path, which works famously.

```
Sub test()

Dim MyPath As String, mps As Variant, mps_temp As String, mydate As Date, i As Integer

MyPath = "G:\Inbox\Folder1\Received\2019 03 01\2019 03 02\2019 03 05\Final"
mps = Split(MyPath, "\")

For i = LBound(mps) To UBound(mps)
    mps_temp = mps(UBound(mps) - i)
    If mps_temp Like "#### ## ##" Then
        mydate = DateSerial(Mid(mps_temp, 1, 4), Mid(mps_temp, 6, 2), Mid(mps_temp, 9, 2))
        Exit For
    End If
Next

msgbox mydate 

End Sub
```

The other items returned are listed on an Excel worksheet to provide a complete inventory of all files. System files (like 'thumbs.db') should not be included in this inventory. I want to do this at the VBA level, and not filter out on the sheet afterwards.

I am looking to return .pdf, .txt, .doc. I don't want .db or temp files of any kind. I may add user input on file type in the future.

Comment: This depends on if you only want certain files, or only *dont* want certain files. What are you looking for?

Comment: Good question....it will probably be easier to specify what types to return, rather than what to exclude (with a future option of user input, maybe). Looking to return .pdf, .txt, .doc. I don't want .db or temp files of any kind.

Comment: I recommend adding that to your question so people who may be able to answer can figure out what's asked of them straight away. It's also very useful to include the code you currently have - as a lot of people will skip over this question if they don't see code

Comment: Am I missing the bit where it get's the files?

Comment: You are not missing something, Nathan, but I might be. I just want the output to skip the system type files. Do I have to return file types and filter out that way? I thought it would be possible at the path level, but maybe not.